# Change View and UI with AngularJS

Tags: html, angularjs, ejs

i got 2 views and i want to switch between them.

My first view (index.ejs) looks like this and is a dashboard for all users before they login (OnePager: For registration and infos):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="app" class="no-js">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>app.com</title>
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="../css/style.css">
  <script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js'></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div ng-view></div>
    <script src="../lib/angular/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="../lib/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="../lib/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
    <script src="../lib/angular-resource/angular-resource.js"></script>  
    <script src="../js/app.js"></script>
    <script src="../js/controllers/indexCtrl.js"></script>
    <script src="../js/services/Api.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

after authentication with passport i want to switch to this (home.ejs) :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="app" class="no-js">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>app.com</title>
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="../css/style.css">
  <script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js'></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/1.7.3/socket.io.js"></script>
        <script>
            var socket = io();
        </script>
</head>
<body>
<SOME OTHER HTML INCLUDED SIDEBARS & TOP BARS>
  <div ng-view></div>
    <script src="../lib/angular/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="../lib/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="../lib/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
    <script src="../lib/angular-resource/angular-resource.js"></script>  
    <script src="../js/app.js"></script>
    <script src="../js/controllers/homeCtrl.js"></script>
    <script src="../js/services/Api.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

So my side- and top- bar should stay static like a SPA and just change the ng-view by navigating through the routes.

What is the best way to do this?

Thanks, Chzn

Answer (score 0):

First of all, there's no need to declare all the scripts in the home.ejs because once you put them in the index they stay available for all the app defined in the tag ng-app. Now, for your question itself what you could do is just create your html code in a separate file and add its reference in the index file and put the next statement in the js script of your ng-app :

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/home', { templateUrl: home.html, controller:homeController });
    $routeProvider.otherwise({ redirectTo: '/' });
}]);

app.controller('mainController', ['$scope', $location, function($scope, $routeProvider){
    $location.path( "/home" );
}])
```

And that's all you just need to put the mainController inside the ng-controller tag in the index and that could work I think.

Let me know if it helps,

Comment: First big thanks for the fast answer. But i actually know all of this. how to use the route provider and how to show the partial pages from a seperate file. But my main question is how i can get a static side and topbar like the Twitch SPA [link](https://www.twitch.tv/) . I want to load the index file without static top and sidebars. It looks like this on curse [link](http://www.curse.com/) . After authentication load static top and sidebars and just change the ng-view via routeprovider like the twitch app in the first link does.

Answer (score 0):

Well i found it out myself. What am i looking for was nested views (child views). It can be easily done with ui-router from the guys of angular. Which can be found here https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router